# Spring: how to ignore @Autowired property if bean is not defined

Tags: spring

**Situation**: I have I class with property annotated with @Autowired:

```
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    protected MyAutoWiredBean myAutowiredBean;
}
```

Is there any possibility to made wiring this bean optional, i.e. if such bean is defined in some configuration file - to wire it, but if such bean is not defined - just continue working without throwing:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: protected MyAutoWiredBean...; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:      
No matching bean of type [com.mypackage.MyAutoWiredBean] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
@Autowired(required=false)
```

[Javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html):

> Declares whether the annotated dependency is required. Defaults to `true`

Answer (score 6):

you can set required attribute like :

```
@Autowired(required=false)
```

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.5/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html