# When "No qualifying bean of type found for dependency" is ok

Tags: spring

I've created a bean that expects to be injected with all beans of a given type... something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
  private List<MyOtherBean> myOtherBeansList;
  ....
  @Inject
  public void setMyOtherBeanList(List<MyOtherBean> otherBeanList) {
    this.myOtherBeansList = otherBeanList;
  }
```

This works fine, except when I have no beans of type 'MyOtherBeans' defined.  In my business logic, that's ok!  But spring doesn't like it and throws the overly familiar:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type...
```

exception.  Does anyone know of a way to get spring to just pass me null in that case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring: how to ignore @Autowired property if bean is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686723/spring-how-to-ignore-autowired-property-if-bean-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind.. I'm dumb.

@Autowired(required=false)

Comment: `required` on [`@Inject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html)? Didn't you mean [`@Autowired`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html#required--)? -> http://stackoverflow.com/q/19485878/1240557

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  Inject and Autowired are synonymous in behavior, so I just assumed.  I had switched to Autowired in my code to try to resolve the issue, and didn't bother checking Inject.  Mea Culpa.  Edited.

Comment: See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485878/can-inject-be-made-optional-in-jsr-330-like-autowirerequired-false?lq=1) for more info on my error.